# JavaScript stroke fill on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, kineticjs

I'm trying to to make it possible for an image on a canvas to have a box over it with low opacity, to make it be shown that it has been selected. So I need an onclick function, but i'm stuck on what to do. Any advice? I would aslo appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction on how to make the box also pulsate.

```
                var image1 = new Kinetic.Image({
                    image: imageObj,
                    x: xposition,
                    y: yposition,
                    width: width,
                    height: height,
                    stroke: 'blue',
                    srokeFill: 'red',
                    strokeWidth: 5,
                    draggable: true,
                    dragBoundFunc: function (pos) {
                       if (pos.x < this.minX)
                            this.minX = pos.x;
                        return {
                            x: pos.x,
                            y: this.getAbsolutePosition().y                                 
                        }
                    }


                });

                layer.on('mouseover', function (evt) {
                    var shape = evt.target;
                    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                    shape.strokeEnabled(true);
                    layer.draw();
                });

                layer.on('mouseout', function (evt) {
                    var shape = evt.target;
                    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
                    shape.strokeEnabled(false);
                    layer.draw();

                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making a clickable region on a canvas you need to.

```
- Create a redraw function.
- Find the mouse point inside of canvas.
- Do collision detection on the mouse point and region.
```

update: added multiple clickable regions.

```js
// x1, y1, x2, y2, clicked
var boxes = [{
  x1: 10,
  y1: 10,
  x2: 110,
  y2: 110,
  clicked: false
}, {
  x1: 120,
  y1: 10,
  x2: 220,
  y2: 110,
  clicked: false
}];

function go() {
  var can = document.getElementById('can');
  var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  var w = can.width;
  var h = can.height;

  makeNoise(ctx);

  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
  var mx = 0;
  var my = 0;

  $('#can').mousemove(function(event) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    mx = event.pageX - offset.left;
    my = event.pageY - offset.top;
    redraw();
  });

  $('#can').click(function(event) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    mx = event.pageX - offset.left;
    my = event.pageY - offset.top;

    for (var i = 0, len = boxes.length; i < len; i++) {
      var b = boxes[i];
      if (hit(b.x1, b.y1, b.x2, b.y2)) {
        b.clicked = !b.clicked;
      }
    }

    redraw();
  });

  function redraw() {
    // Draw the original image
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    // Draw the clickable region

    for (var i = 0, len = boxes.length; i < len; i++) {
      drawBox(boxes[i]);
    }
    // Draw the mouse. Probably only needed when testing
    // mouse location.
    drawMouse();
  }

  redraw();

  // Collision dection of a square against mouse point.
  // square points x1,y1 must be less than x2,y2
  function hit(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    if (mx < x1 || my < y1 || mx > x2 || my > y2) return false;
    return true;
  }

  function drawMouse() {
    ctx.moveTo(mx, my);
    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(mx, my, 5, 0, Math.PI * 360);
    ctx.fill();
  }

  function drawBox(b) {

    if (b.clicked) {
      // Mouse clicked.
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,255,.5)"
    } else if (hit(b.x1, b.y1, b.x2, b.y2)) {
      // Mouse Over
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,.5)"
    } else {
      // Mouse Out
      ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    }

    ctx.fillRect(b.x1, b.y1, b.x2 - b.x1, b.y2 - b.y1);

  }
}

// Fill a canvas context with noise.
function makeNoise(ctx) {
  var can = ctx.canvas;
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
  var d = imageData.data;
  for (var i = 0, len = d.length; i < len; i += 4) {
    d[i] = d[i + 1] = d[i + 2] = (Math.random() * 8) << 4;
    d[i + 3] = 255;
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

go();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="can" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: @user5071855 The noise isn't needed. I added it to show the transparency effect.  Where I'm drawing noise you'll probably want to draw the image. You can see that imageData is collected after noise to redraw the background.

Comment: thanks for explaining and giving me a example I've been searching for ages!